# fetching array as data from db removes [ and " "

Tags: php

My fetching Code is like:

```
 <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("planning", $con);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT sewing_end FROM tbl_input");

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $category['data'][] = mysql_escape_string($r['sewing_end']);   
}

print json_encode($category['data']);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

My output is:

```
["2015-09-20","2015-09-30","2015-09-25","2015-09-19","2015-09-08","2015-09-07","2015-09-16","2015-09-12","2015-09-10","2015-09-03"]
```

Now, I want to remove `[]` and `" "` when I fetch my data from DB.

Comment: ok, so, what have you tried to remove [ ] and " " ?

Comment: yes, I want to remove [] and " ".

Comment: Please google array php and you can able to get it

Comment: Have you tried something like `print implode(',', $category['data']);`?!!

Comment: Your output is JSON encoded which is why you are getting the [].

Comment: Why do you want to remove them? What is the reason?

Comment: ohh, It's work!!. @someone. Can i print the data in ' ' instead of " "?

Comment: thank's @Blaze Sahlzen

Comment: What do you mean?! If you want to enclose the output with single quotation marks, then simply do: `print "'" . implode(',', $category['data']) . "'";`!

Comment: if you want to remove [] and " from the output which is i assume is string then you can use `str_replace` like this: `str_replace(array('[',']','"',"",$output));`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
$dates = $category['data'];


foreach($dates as $date){
    echo "'".$date."'";
    echo "<br/>";
}
```